# Angular component (with a directive) testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular8

I have a component I want to test. The test fails with message

> AdminPanelComponent > should create
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined
>
> error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view:
>   Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 50577443,
>   rootNodeFlags: 1, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({
>   nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0,
>   outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 1, childFlags: 50577443,
>   directChildFlags: 1, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({ 
>   }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex:
>   null, childCount: 11, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ],
>   element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'div', attrs: [ Array ], template:
>   null, componentProvider: null, componentView: null,
>   componentRendererType: null, publicProviders: null({  }),
>   allProviders: null({  }), handleEvent: Function }), provider: null,
>   text: null, query: null, ngContent: null }), Object({ nodeIndex: 1,
>   parent: Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null,
>   bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 1, childFlags:
>   50577443, directChildFlags: 1, chi ...
>       at 
>       at HasRoleDirective.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/_directives/hasRole.directive.ts:16:53)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:26276:1)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:37133:1)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:37072:1)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:38094:36)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:38037:1)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/AdminPanelComponent.ngfactory.js:62:5)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:38025:1)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:37037:1)
>       at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:37403:1)

**admin-panel.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-panel',
  templateUrl: './admin-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-panel.component.css']
})
export class AdminPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**admin-panel.component.html**

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h2>Admin panel</h2>
  <div class="tab-panel">
    <tabset class="member-tabset">
      <tab heading="User Management" *appHasRole="['Admin']">
        <div class="container">
            <app-user-management></app-user-management>  
        </div>        
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Photo management" *appHasRole="['Admin', 'Moderator']">
        <app-photo-management></app-photo-management>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

**hasRole.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasRole]'
})
export class HasRoleDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() appHasRole: string[];
  isVisible = false;

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const userRoles = this.authService.decodedToken.role as Array<string>;
    // if no roles clear the viewContainerRef
    if (!userRoles) {
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    }

    // if user has role need to render the element
    if (this.authService.roleMatch(this.appHasRole)) {
      if (!this.isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = true;
        this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      } else {
        this.isVisible = false;
        this.viewContainerRef.clear();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code part that is failing to work is

`const userRoles = this.authService.decodedToken.role as Array<string>;`

How do I test this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to test an angular app is to mock everything except the component you want to test.

The easiest way to do it is to use a lib like [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks).

Nevertheless you need to stub the AuthService like that

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [HasRoleDirective, AdminPanelComponent],
  provides: [
    {
      provide: AuthService,
      useValue: {
        decodedToken: {
          role: [], // <- you can put here values for the test
        },
        roleMatch: () => false, // <- or to use a spy here.
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

in this case AuthService will be a stub with fake methods that don't do anything.

Comment: Thank you, looks easier than I thought initialy.